# Updated 4.3 Getting Error: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to

Tags: plugins, errors

I've updated to 4.3, now I'm getting this error!

Error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_admin_bar_customize_menu' not found or invalid function name in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/seminar/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 571

Comment: I am guessing you have an incomplete/broken upgrade. Does your `plugin.php` match [this one](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/plugin.php) (just check near line 571)?

Comment: Do you have wp-includes/admin-bar.php in which that function is defined?

Comment: You're correct the upgrade was somehow incomplete. I reupdated it and it worked. Thanks again!